# If $\bf L$ is constant in time why can we write ${\bf L} \times \frac{d\bf{p}}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\left({\bf L} \times {\bf p}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, vectors

The title says it all really, but for context, I am trying to understand just one small part of the derivation of the Lenz vector for the hydrogen atom as shown here:

[image: Lenz vector]

Okay, so ${\bf L}= \mathrm{constant}\implies \frac{d{\bf L}}{dt}=0$.

But why does $\bf L$ being constant in time allow the author to pull the time derivative operating on the momentum, $\bf p$, out front like this $${\bf L} \times \frac{d\bf{p}}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\left({\bf L} \times {\bf p}\right)?$$

Or, put in another way, what rule says that the time derivative can be commuted past the product of two vectors (one of them being time-independent)?

---

I'm sorry if this is so blatantly obvious to most of you but it is not clear to me.

Comment: Do you know the cross product rule?

Comment: @themathandlanguagetutor Yes, I know that one, it's the same as the vector product right?

Comment: Whenever you see an equation you don't understand, you should try working it backwards since equation signs work both ways. In this case, start from $\frac{d}{dt}(L \times p)$ and expand this out.

Comment: @Merosity $\frac{d}{dt}\left({\bf L} \times {\bf p}\right)=\frac{d{\bf L}}{dt}\times {\bf p} + {\bf L}\times\frac{d{\bf p}}{dt}={\bf L}\times\frac{d{\bf p}}{dt}$ understood. Many thanks!

Comment: @themathandlanguagetutor Is the "cross product rule" what I just used in my last comment? Sorry for asking, I just have not heard that terminology before.

Comment: @FutureCop its the product rule. I've never heard of the cross product rule.

Comment: Its best to verify this manually one time to know for sure, let $L = (L_1, L_2, L_3)$ and $p = (p_1, p_2, p_3)$ so $\frac{dp}{dt} = ( \frac{dp_1}{dt}, \frac{dp_2}{dt}, \frac{dp_3}{dt} ) $  and $\frac{dL}{dt} = (0,0,0)$ now just verify that $ \frac{d}{dt} ( L \times p) = L \times \frac{dp}{dt} $ Recall that for a term like $\frac{d}{dt} [ L_k p_r ] = \frac{dL_k}{dt}p_r + L_k \frac{dp_r}{dt}  = 0 + L_k \frac{dp_2}{dt}$

Comment: @FutureCop Yes, that's the product rule. I asked about the cross product rule because it was shorter than asking about the product rule applying to the cross product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It follows from the product rule for cross products, which looks exactly as you would expect:
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(\boldsymbol u\times\boldsymbol v)=\dot{\boldsymbol u}\times\boldsymbol v+\boldsymbol u\times \dot{\boldsymbol v}$$
Where I have used dots as the standard shorthand for time derivatives. Note that the order of $\boldsymbol u,\boldsymbol v$ is important here. As for a proof, you can either verify this manually, or use index notation and the Levi-Civita symbol:
$$\begin{align}(u\times v)^i&=\epsilon^i{}_{jk}u^jv^k \\ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(u\times v)^i&=\epsilon^i{}_{jk}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(u^jv^k) \\ &=\epsilon^i{}_{jk}(\dot{u}^jv^k+\dot{v}^ku^j) \\ &=\epsilon^i{}_{jk}\dot{u}^jv^k+\epsilon^i{}_{jk}u^j\dot{v}^k \\ &=(\dot{u}\times v)^i+(u\times \dot{v})^i\end{align}$$